# Transie & Gambas

Tags: gambas3

I am trying to install transie (https://sourceforge.net/projects/transie/) a dual pane text editor. 
Running 19.04, I get the following error:

Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: gambas2-qb-qt(>=1.9.48)

Is there a way to fix this? I've tried to contact the developer but the email bounced.

Comment: Did you also try to install gambas? https://sourceforge.net/projects/gambas/

Comment: Yes. Not sure what version installs from the repositories.

Comment: ? Download and install it from the SF page... ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like development halted in 2010.  The link to their wiki fails, too. I found the wiki at http://sourceforge.net/p/transie/wiki/Home but there's not a whole lot there.